# Laravel Referencing To Mother Query

Tags: laravel

I have this eloquent queries :

```
$result = Model::whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to]);

$active_records = $result->where('status_id', 1)->get();
$pending_records = $result->where('status_id', 2)->get();
$closed_records = $result->where('status_id', 3)->get();
```

My problem is that the query on `$active_records` has affected the queries on `$closed_records` and `$pending_records`.

How can I make the two last queries to reference the original `$result` query?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: oh, i forgot to say, sorry, it's laravel 5.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you instead of doing 4 db query, you can do just one query, after that, you can use `Laravel Collection` to filter your list, so your code will be like this and that confirm `$active_records` will not affect `$closed_records` :

```
$result = Model::whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])->get();

$active_records = $result->where('status_id', 1);
$pending_records = $result->where('status_id', 2);
$closed_records = $result->where('status_id', 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
$result = Model::whereIn('status_id', [1, 2, 3])
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$date_from, $date_to])
    ->get();

$active_records = $result->where('status_id', 1);
$pending_records = $result->where('status_id', 2);
$closed_records = $result->where('status_id', 3);
```